# Passport.js failure message is not appearing

Tags: node.js, authentication, heroku, passport.js, passport-local

I have the passport.js authentication and it accepts correct credentials and not incorrect.

I am trying to make a pop up message appear appear for incorrect credentials.

tried numerous attempts and by following the documentation but cannot get it to work.
There doesnt seem to be too much in it but cant get it quite right.

Setting up strategy

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var app = express();
app.use(flash());

passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' } ); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' }); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));
```

Authentication - Post and Get

```
//Log In Post request
app.post('/login.post',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
                                   failureRedirect: '/',
                                   failureFlash: 'Invalid log in, please try again' })
);


//Home route
app.get('/home', //Log in Home
  function(req, res) {
   res.render('home', { user: req.user });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
// Login Process
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/auth/login",

    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Calling `(req, res, next);` is important otherwise the whole thing will just stuck there.

Comment: Or just...

`router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/auth/login', failureFlash: true }));`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

Comment: Dumb question  is `var flash  = require("connect-flash")` and not only `require("flash")`?

Comment: Yeah i have that, added to this example though thanks!

Comment: And a simple test like `req.flash("success", "Test sample");` works?

Comment: Added that to my app.get for home (and other pages) and no it didnt work, no errors but no notifications.

Comment: Check this repo for a full sample with LocalStrategy and flash

https://github.com/Colt/yelp-camp-refactored